# Compare two bmpn 2.0 files

Tags: bpmn

I've two BMPN 2.0 files mades in two differents tools. Both process is the same, but i've to demonstrate it by a tool.
Anybody knows some tool that I can use it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. These might help you:

> A curated list of bpmn.io related projects and resources. Created in
>   the spirit of awesome.

https://github.com/bpmn-io/awesome-bpmn-io

and more specifically to your challenge:

https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-differ

> A semantic diffing utility for BPMN 2.0 files. To be used together
>   with bpmn-moddle.
>
> The diff returns an object with the _changed, _added, _removed,
>   _layoutChanged keys containing all differences between the models.